# Escape characters used in plsql packages

Tags: regex, oracle

Is there any meaning for '\2' in plsql.
I am seeing the below expresion is used quite a lot.

```
regexp_replace(variable, '[*]','\2')
```

Comment: This isn't a PL/SQL thing. Regular expressions in general and Oracle SQL regexp_ functions specifically use `\1` etc for back references.

Answer (score 2):

In the expression `Regexp_replace(variable, '[*]', '\2')` then `\2` is a back-reference referring to the second capturing group in the regular expression.

However, in your expression, the `'[*]'` regular expression does not have any `()` capturing groups so it will not match anything and would just replace each `*` character with nothing.

If you had `Regexp_replace(variable, '(abc)(def)(ghi)', '\2')` then the capturing groups will match `abc` in the first group, `def` in the second group and then `ghi` in the third capturing group and will replace the entire `abcdefghi` match with the contents of the second capturing group, which is only `def`.